# share log4net configuration between solutions

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

I have two seperate solutions (frontend, backend). They share a common project that handles logging, called Logging.proj (just a class library).

Frontend solution is just a website, there I have my log4net.config in the root and the register it in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

But when calling my WCF backend solution I can't get and register log4net.config.

I tried to add log4net.config inside Loggin.proj root and register in Loggin.proj/AssemblyInfo.cs, but it doesn't seems to find and being able to register it..

I would like to have a common log4net.config file shared between 2 different solutions.

Comment: Seems more to do with registering L4N with WCF than any concern over sharing config files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312109/log4net-for-wcf-service-library-hosted-in-iis

Comment: so i need to register it in all the assemblyinfo.cs - classes where I'm using my Logging.proj?