# Log4Net logger class not creating file when called from WCF Service Library Project?

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

Have this Log4net class in a class library project. When accessed from a windows application after using the .dll, the file is created and log is written.

When using the same .dll of my class library project in my WCF service library project, the file is not created at all.

The way i write to the log from windows application and the wcf service library project is exactly same as below.

Why is the behavior different when called from WCF ?

How I call the logger class from other projects in the same solution :

```
public Logger Logger;
Logger = Logger.Instance();
Logger.Debug("Product Service is called");
```

Logger Class in Class Library Project :

```
    public class Logger
{
    private static volatile Logger instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private static log4net.ILog logger = null;
    private object _lock = new object();

    private Logger()
    {
        if (logger == null)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerManager");
        } 
    }

    public static Logger Instance()
    { 
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new Logger();
            }
        } 
        return instance;
    } 


    public void Info(string info, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            logger.Info(string.Format("Info : {0} in member {1}, file {2} at line {3}", info, memberName, filePath, lineNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

log4net.config.xml :

```
  <log4net debug="false">
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\Logs\App.Log" />
    <threshold value="ALL" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="*%-10level %-30date %message [%logger] [%thread] %newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="Logger">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  </logger> 

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" /> 
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `<log4net>` section in the appropriate `app.config` file for your WCF service? If it is missing, the log file will not be created.

**Edit**

After tracking down the problem in a chat room, the solution was to copy the missing `log4net.config.xml` in the output directory of the WCF dll. Then the logfile appeared.

Comment: Why should I have the log4net <section> in my app.config of WCF service project ? It is configured in another project where logger class resides. And the windows application which writes to log has no such log4net <section> in it's app.config, but still it works.

Comment: I do not want to have the log4net configuration in all the projects or reference to log4net dll.  I do have a separate class library for such purpose and it will be shared. Want to achieve in that way. Possible ?

Comment: When you start your WCF service, only the `app.config` of the WCF service will be loaded. So there must be the `<log4net>` section.

The `<log4net>` section must be only in the `app.config` of the project you start.
e.g. you have the libraries `lib1.dll`, `lib2.dll`, your WCF service `service.exe` and a windows application `app.exe`. All four use `log4net`. Then you need the `log4net` section in the `app.config` of `service.exe` and in the `app.config` of `app.exe`.

Comment: I don't get it when my Windows application is able to do it without the log4net <section> in its app.config. May be because the output of win app is .exe ? Anyway I tried adding in my wcf service library application app.config as you suggested. But still not working !!!  Note : it is not service.exe, it is service.dll. Because it is WCF Service Library project and not WCF Service Application project

Comment: Ah. Didn't get you ("...to do it without the log4net <section> in its app.config..."). Where is the log4net file located when you start your exe? Do you configure log4net by code?

Comment: If you host in IIS, look at this post [where to place your config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312109/log4net-for-wcf-service-library-hosted-in-iis) (scroll down to last answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181324/discussion-between-anuya-and-jurgen-muller).

Comment: I run my WCF service library app from WCF test client (WCF Service Host)

Comment: "to do it without the log4net <section> in its app.config" I meant, I did not add any log4net related things in my Windows Application config. But still it works

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer. Thank you and happy coding.